# htaccess file not working on godaddy and mod_rewrite is not show when echo phpinfo

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? admin.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I am very frusted .htaccces file not working with godaddy server please help me...i want redirect on admin.php page but working on local server in XAMPP..

Comment: IS IT WINDOWS SERVER OR LINUX ?

Comment: Hosting on Linux Server ..

Comment: If you're not getting 500 then `RewriteEngine` is probably working. You need to see if .htaccess is enabled like putting some garbage text on top

Comment: have u check that mod_rewrite is enable or not

Comment: @anubhava i am getting 500 error..

Comment: internal server error ! i think reason behind this is ur htaccess you code might be have some problem

Comment: @JanakPrajapati yaa we check mod_rewrite is not show and we also mail to godaddy supprt team that reply mod_rewrite by default is on...

Comment: Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine` line **`RewriteRule ^foo$ bar [L,R]`** then open url `http://site/com/foo` to if this gets redirected to `http://site/com/bar` or not.

Answer (score 0):

please follow this artical may this will help u

http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/redirect-htaccess-godaddy-hosting-not-working/